# How to rename formula installed via Homebrew?

Tags: macos, terminal, homebrew

I installed gcc with homebrew:

```
$ brew install gcc
```

I can see the result:

```
$ brew list
ant         gcc     go          libyaml     postgresql  tmux
autoconf    gdb     isl         mpfr        python      valgrind
automake    gdbm    libevent    openssl     readline    wget
binutils    git     libmpc      ossp-uuid   ruby        xz
cloog       gmp     libtool     pkg-config  sqlite
```

I also see `gcc-4.9` in `/usr/local/bin`

```
$ ls /usr/local/bin
...
gcc-4.9
...
```

The issue is that typing `gcc` still refers to the system gcc

```
$ which gcc
/usr/bin/gcc
```

I wanted to rename `gcc-4.9` to `gcc`, but I don't want to break anything in homebrew. Specifically, I'd like to rename it in such a way that homebrew is aware of the change and running `brew update` will know to link the newly updated version to the name `gcc` in `/usr/local/bin`.

Can this be done?

DESIRED BEHAVIOR:

```
$ which gcc
/usr/local/bin/gcc
$ gcc -v
... version XXX
$ brew update
... new gcc version YYY installed in /usr/local/bin/gcc
$ which gcc
/usr/local/bin/gcc
$ gcc -v
... version YYY
```

Comment: You can rename `/usr/bin/gcc` to something else and create `gcc` symlink to `/usr/local/bin/gcc-4.9`.

Comment: I usually just put an alias in my `.bash_profile` that refers to the one I want. Hackish way of doing it, but it works.

Answer (score 3):

I don't think what you want can be done directly without hacking Homebrew formulas, er, I mean formulae.

What I do is put

```
export CC=gcc-4.9
```

in my shell profile.  That works in almost all scenarios I'm interested in.

An alternative is that you create your own "bin" directory, say `~/bin/`, put that first in the path, and symlink `~/bin/gcc` to `/usr/local/bin/gcc-4.9`.

Both of these methods will survive package upgrades.